# PHP PDO dynamically getting data

Tags: php, pdo

Would this code work? If not, what are my options?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ?");
$stmt->execute( array( $column1 => $value1, $column2 => $value2 ) );
```

Comment: No, it won't work.  You have to concatenate in those placeholders by dynamically building the prepared statement. And if they come from user input, you have to do it very carefully, via whitelists.

Comment: If you post more info about the sources of `$column1, $column2`, someone will be able to offer a concrete suggestion.

Comment: Please read the documentation about PDO before posting here. Its very clear described there how to use Prepared Statements. http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to supply the table field names, the values can be substituted.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = :value1 AND column2= :value2");
$stmt->execute( array( ':value1' => $value1, ':value2' => $value2 ) );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php